# Is there a problem in Saints Row 4 on the Switch?

Tags: technical-issues, nintendo-switch, saints-row-iv

So I get out of the simulation and driving the spaceship, and when I complete the level, it stays on the loading screen for hours, ad I still haven't passed it.

Comment: That does sound like a glitch - even in Saints Row 4 there isn't any jokes related to the loading screen. Try restarting your game